# iOS App bug uploading pics from iPhone 7 asked me to post to Meta

Tags: bug, images, editing

The iOS App got stuck uploading a photo. I was getting this error:

[image]

It wouldn’t upload from the originals (2) in-spite of trying several times.

So I tried a joined layout and it worked. Maybe because the overall size was less?

But shouldn't the iOS App account for pictures taken on the phone?

[image]

Comment: There's a size limit of 2MBytes per image. If you're using the desktop version of the site, it displays a tooltip with that information when you click on the _Image_ button in the post editor. I don't have an iOS device so I don't know if that information is displayed there.

Comment: @NiallC. - Should the iOS App not account for this limit or mention thats the issue instead having us post into Meta. And we cant see Image File Size when using the App, so SE you guys have to account for it somehow.